# How to get color of pixel in coordinates 123, 456 in screen?

Tags: applescript, screen

My AppleScript app needs to get color of pixel in coordinates 123, 456 in screen.

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to do this using only built-in components:

```
do shell script "screencapture -R123,456,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && \
                 xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | \
                 sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"
```

Output is the color in hex, for example, `ffffff` for white.

The `screencapture` command takes a 1x1 screenshot of the coordinates, and outputs it in the bmp format to a temporary location.

The `xxd` command reads 3 bytes from that file at offset 54. 54 is the length of the header in the generated bmp file, and the next 3 bytes are the color of the pixel.

The `sed` command swaps the first two characters of the output with the last two. This is because the bmp stores the colors in reverse of the normal order - `BBGGRR`. This command swaps the order to the normal `RRGGBB`.

Comment: Damn you for trumping my answer.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, but only if you chain together multiple events:

1. Take a screenshot `do shell script "screencapture -l" & windowid & " ~/test.png"`
2. Crop around the specific pixel using [ImageMagick](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/)

Output:

```
convert ~/test.png -crop 1x1+123+456 txt:-
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,rgba
0,0: (  0, 74,117,251)  #004A75FB  rgba(0,74,117,0.984314)
```

The idea is to crop around a specific pixel, then output it to the special txt: format, with an output file name of - which is of course standard output.

You can leave out the the -crop 1x1+X+Y business to just get a listing of all pixels. Also note that you image must have an alpha channel to see the alpha channel, otherwise it just won't get included.

Comment: Every time I think that's the craziest question that no way will someone know an answer, do I happen upon an awesome answer like this that just nails it. Internet FTW!

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, but maybe Cocoa could do this too?

Comment: Doubtful that you can do it natively.  Although, if it does work for you, I would be honored to get a lil' green checkbox for the answer :)